# Delphi FireMonkey - is there a way to clip a canvas with non-rectangular area?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

On Delphi FireMonkey when we draw on the canvas we have

```
Canvas.IntersectClipRect(ARect)
```

to make that all paint done outside aRect will be ignored.

It works great but for rectangular area. Is there any way to set a clipping area with a non-rectangular area?

Thank you by advance.

**Upd**: I noted FireMonkey because i would like to find some cross-platform solution. I found some Windows-related answers like [this one](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/10168790/Clipping-on-a-TCanvas.html). But unfortunately it will be not applicable for Android etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [`TPathData`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TPathData) to define non-rectangular paths for use with [`TCanvas.DrawPath()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.DrawPath) and [`TCanvas.FillPath()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.FillPath).